# python recursion - reusing function output

Tags: python

I need to run `calc(a,b)` 10 times but after the first iteration, I want to pass it's output which is a tuple as a parameter.

```
def test(a,b, count = 1):
    if count == 10:
        return
    cr = calc(a,b)
    return test(cr[0],cr[1], count+1)
```

`print(test(10,4))` returns None

Comment: In the base case, `return` means `return None`, and this returned value is propagated to the original caller.

Comment: What do you want `test(10,4)` to return? And please give the definition of `calc` also, so that your question becomes Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns none because you are not returning anything
add, `return cr`, also ensure you define `cr` before you attempt to return it

```
def test(a,b, count = 1):
    cr = calc(a,b)
    if count == 10:
        return cr
    return test(cr[0],cr[1], count+1)
```